# install has detected an invalid Active EMD Home configured as </some/path/>

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

"Possible cause for this error may be a previous installation of Oracle Application Server that was not completely installed or deinstalled. Please perform a deinstall on that home."

I believe I have deinstalled it, together with the database. And when I use runInstaller and choose deinstall, it doesn't show up.

Asking google yields 6 or 7 results, and all but one seems to be from the same person asking in different forums.

Running

```
find . -type f |xargs grep "10.1.2"|grep -v "./logs/"
```

in the oraInventory folder tells me this:

```
Binary file ./Contents/OracleHomesList.ser matches
Binary file ./Contents/PatchesList2.ser matches
Binary file ./Contents/CompsList2.ser matches
...
Binary file ./sessionContext.ser matches
./backup/2009-06-21_12-38-20AM/ContentsXML/inventory.xml:<HOME NAME="oracleas1" LOC="/some/folder/10.1.2/as_1" TYPE="O" IDX="2"/>
```

I'd rather not edit binary oracle files without instructions, or wipe the disk, so if someone has an idea, I am listening.

(In case anyone wonders how I got into this I guess it might be because I uninstalled forms and reports (32 bit) together with the database unsin the database uninstaller (64 bit).)

Comment: Do you have other Oracle Homes on the box that you need to salvage, or is it okay to essentially wipe all traces of Oracle off the box so you can start fresh?

Comment: I'd rather not wipe the database, as I consider it a lot of work to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed for now by pointing inventory_loc in oraInst.loc to another location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you physically deleted the directory corresponding to the deinstalled EMD home? I know the agent doesn't like it if you try to reinstall without doing this.

Comment: Yes I moved it to tmp so just in case it didn't work I could put it back again.